# Webforms Application - Intercept a 404 Not Found for folders in code during the request inside the asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, http-status-code-404

Long time MVC developer, first time WebForms developer. I've been googling this for quite some time and I'm at a lose.

1. Create new WebForms application
2. Run
3. Visit ~/blah.aspx
4. Application_Error triggered and asp.net 404 page shown
5. Visit ~/blah

Expected

```
Application_Error triggered and asp.net 404 page shown
```

Actual

```
Application_Error not triggered and IIS 404 page shown
```

In an MVC application, there's the notion of a catch all route that could handle folders not found.

1. `<system.web><customErrors>` Does not handle folders not found.
2. `<system.webServer><httpErrors>` Does handle folders not found, but is handle later than I need. It is handled after asp.net returned the 404. Plus, I'm working in a multi-tenant website with many Sub-Applications and `<httpErrors path` does not play well with relative paths.

I need a solution that I can detect the 404 (file and folder) in the Application_Error event.

I even explored detecting if the path exists in the Application_BeginRequest event and throwing a new HttpException(404, but this does not play well with using Bundles and virtual paths. I suppose I could always ensure bundles map to physical paths, but only if I have to.

What's the best way to handle this in a WebForms application with out modifying the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting in TrySkipIisCustomErrors Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
   HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}
```

for 404 you can also do this:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{

   if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
   }

}
```

Comment: That would be great, but Application_Error is never triggered for folders that don't exist. That is the essence of the issue. What happens is asp.net throws up it's arms and says to IIS, this path doesn't exist.